# WordPress independent plugin upgrade notification system

Tags: plugins, notifications, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update plugin from personal API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/update-plugin-from-personal-api)

I have seen wordpress sending alerts for the plugins those have upgrades available in the dashboard. this is done to the plugin hosted on the worpdress. But how we manage same alert notification system with the plugin that is not hosted on the wordpress. In other wordpress how paid plugins manage upgrade notification

Thanks in advance

Comment: Voting close, please use the search, this has been asked many times.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here : http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates/

PS: GIYF...